# Icons from DigitalOcean spaces can't load with my Django settings

Tags: python-3.x, django, devops, digital-ocean

I am using Django summernote, but icons aren't showing, this is the structure of my digitalocean spaces :

[image]

When it comes to Django settings, I pointed to the `res` folder with `AWS_LOCATION`, but am not sure if the path I provided is correct, I used :

`AWS_LOCATION = 'res/'`

I also enabled CORS in the DigitalOCean spaces section, but I am still getting this error :

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/guio_space/res/vendor/adminlte/css/adminlte.min.css.map: HTTP error: status code 403, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/guio_space/res/vendor/adminlte/js/adminlte.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 403, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/guio_space/res/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 403, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
all.min.css:1          GET https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/guio_space/res/vendor/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2 net::ERR_ABORTED 403
all.min.css:1          GET https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/guio_space/res/vendor/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff2 net::ERR_ABORTED 403
all.min.css:1          GET https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/guio_space/res/vendor/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff net::ERR_ABORTED 403
all.min.css:1          GET https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/guio_space/res/vendor/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff net::ERR_ABORTED 403
all.min.css:1          GET https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/guio_space/res/vendor/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf net::ERR_ABORTED 403
all.min.css:1          GET https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/guio_space/res/vendor/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-regular-400.ttf net::ERR_ABORTED 403
logo.png:1
```